# How to add in in appendix page numbers separately from the regular heading page numbers

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, page-numbers

I had regular page numbers on my Microsoft Word 2007 document at the bottom center of my page, starting from 1 from Insert tab > Page Number > Bottom of page > Plain Number 2. I added an appendix with Heading 6 and followed the instructions from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290953 to create separate page numbers just for the appendix, i.e. A-1, A-2, B-1, B-2, etc. The Page Number Format configuration I did is here:

[image]

]When I try to set this however, it changes all of the page numbers to this format, even the ones that aren't from heading 6 (meaning it changes the non-appendix content to this page number format).

Here's another example:
1 Heading1 has page number A-4 (note it starts at A-1 at the title page)
...
Appendix A has page number A-12

I would like to change it so that 
1 Heading1 has page number 4 (note it starts at 1 at the title page)
...
Appendix A has page number A-1

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key thing is this ...

> Make sure that the document contains a section break of some type. The
>   section break type that you want is typically Next Page. **Use the
>   section break to separate the main document area from the appendix
>   area.**

Note that "Heading 6" is the 6th *level* of headings (i.e. sub-sub-sub-sub-sub-headings), not the 6th heading in the document. I expect it is irrelevant to what you are trying to achieve.